# UIWebView Scrolling to top when other link clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UIWebView in a view controller loading local content.  I am intercepting certain links to load in a modal view.  When one of the those links is clicked and I return NO in my shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method I the currently displayed content scrolls to the top.  I need to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not the best solution but you can try this:

Save before open the modal:

```
CGPoint Pos;
for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews)
{
    if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        Pos = scrollView.contentOfSet;
}
```

And then set:

```
for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews)
{
    if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        [scrollView setContentOffset:Pos animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help and is only available in iOS 5 anyway.  The problem doesn't seem to only happen when I present a modal view.  I'm catching a link in the web view's shouldLoadRequest delegate method and returning NO.  That seems to cause the web view to scroll to the top.  I need it to stay where it is.

Comment: scrollsToTop is avalaible since 2.0 and you can try with setContentOffset:animated: too

Comment: Sorry, scrollsToTop is available since 2.0, but you can only access the web view's scrollView since 5.0.  I'm trying to stop the web view from scrolling up.  It sounds like you're directing me to cause it to scroll.  Basically the issue is that whenever a link is clicked, the content automatically scrolls to the top.  I need to have it stay where it was when the link is clicked.  I'm returning NO from the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method already, so I'm not sure what would be cause the scroll or how to stop it.  I can't disable scrolling altogether as I need user scroll.

Comment: Try this idea, is not the best but I can not think of anything better now

Comment: It turns out that the modal view isn't the issue though.  It's doing it when the link in the main web view is clicked.  The actual modal view part can be ignored, I disabled it to test and it still happens.  I edited the question earlier.

Comment: Sorry, this does sound a little confusing.  The original content containing the link is what scrolls.  Not the new content loaded in a separate view.  So I have Page A with a link to Page B somewhere at the bottom.  I click the link.  The delegate method tells the web view not to load the link, but Page A scrolls to the top.

Comment: I'm giving you the points here since you had a legitimate answer.  The issue turned out to be something outside of the web view.  I'll explain in an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  So the problem wasn't the web view.  It was with the html/javascript.  The links I was clicking had an href="#" and were calling a javascript method on click which changed document.location.  It was the href="#" that was causing the scroll.  I changed it to href="javascript: void(0);" and I'm back in business.

Comment: I have the same same problem but here I want to scroll my content in UIWebview but it is not happening I am using the same in iOS 11. How can I make my content scroll to top? is there any specific property, I have href="#" already in my html. Can you please check and help me out